# Oracle varchar2 field blanks vs null

Tags: null, trim, oracle19c

**product version**: **Oracle 19C**

I have a partitioned table `myTable` with a column definition `myCol VARCHAR2(2 BYTE)`

Recently some data has been loaded using SQL Loader and during the loading process  apparently spaces have been loaded to this column when there is no value.
I am trying to treat rows with spaces/blanks as null.

**My question**:
How to find what is contained in the rows that are blank and how to treat those values as null when I select those rows?

When I issue below query I see no rows returned.

```
select * from myTable where trim(myCol) is null
```

I am not able to figure out what is contained in those rows. Please see below debug queries I tried -

```
select '#'||myCol||'#' from myTable ;
```

output

--##

```
select length(myCol) from myTable ;
```

output

--2

```
select ascii(substr(myCol, 1,1)) as myCol_ascii_Post1 from myTable ;
```

output

--0

```
select ascii(substr(myCol, 2,1)) as myCol_ascii_Post2 from myTable ;
```

--0

```
select ascii(substr(myCol, 3,1)) as myCol_ascii_Post3 from myTable ;
```

output

--(null)

```
select DUMP(myCol) from myTable ;
```

output

--Typ=1 Len=2: 0,0

```
select myCol,trim(myCol) as myCol_trim,nvl(trim(myCol),'NULL Value') as myCol_trim_nvl from myTable ;
```

output
-- blank , blank, blank

```
select count(myCol)
from myTable and trim(myCol) is null;
```

output

--0

```
select count(myCol) from myTable and trim(myCol) = '';
```

output

--0

```
select myCol from myTable;
```

output

-- several blank rows

```
select count(myCol) from myTable and ascii(myCol) = 0 order by 1 desc;
```

output

--345051 rows

```
select count(myCol) from myTable and ascii(myCol) > 0 order by 1 desc;
```

output

-- 0 rows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The characters are not spaces or blanks, and the column itself is not null; it has two null *characters*. (See [ASCII](https://www.asciitable.com/) or [Unicode](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00/index.htm).) That's what the dump and ascii calls are showing - character code zero.

So rather than looking for null or spaces, you can look for that pair of characters:

```
select * from myTable where myCol = chr(0) || chr(0);
```

or treat the value as null by trimming that character rather than the default space:

```
select * from myTable where trim(both chr(0) from myCol) is null;
```

Or ltrim/rtrim with that character.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=35aee945d18fa49519ed575f486dce1d) demo; but showing an ID instead of the real value because null characters break output there. (They confuse other clients too; you can't copy from SQL Developer properly, for example.)

Assuming you consider the data load to be incorrect, and the column is nullable, you *might* want to correct the loaded data with:

```
update myTable set myCol = null where myCol = chr(0) || chr(0);
```

or delete the rows using the same filter, if they shouldn't have been loaded at all.

Comment: Awesome Alex! Your both solutions worked! 
The flat file that was loaded came from MainFrame. Do you know what cause the rows to have those two chr(0)s ?

Comment: No, depends what the control file said and how the file was created/populated.